# Recover some data files after OS installation crash

Tags: data-recovery

Ubuntu 16.04
During 18.04 automatic installation system crashed, now I can't access the PC. Start and login end up to the blank purple ubuntu desktop with no possibility to go further.
I need to get back only desktop files and thunderbird files as the whole HD is contantly backuped onto google drive.
Accessing to pc through light ubuntu from usb stick allows me to see all the data files are there. However I cannot retrieve them as I have "no permission".
What can I do?
Best
GA

Comment: If you booted from a USB stick, then you have all the permission you need. Use sudo.

Comment: Can you switch to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4), if so login, and `cp` (`scp`, `rsync` etc) your files from there.  I'm not sure what you meant by 'automatic installation', but since you mentioned 16.04 - I'm assuming you were trying to upgrade to 18.04 (ie. `do-release-upgrade`) so I'd `sudo do-release-upgrade` and have the upgrade process try and continue..

Comment: Thanks for your support but so far none of the suggestions seemed to work. 1. I do boot from USB and choose "try ubuntu", then I do not have any permission as non password is required. I do see all folders and files, but forlders appear with a small X top right and are not accessible, nor files such as those done with libre office, although visible the icon, can be accessed or copied. 2. yes I allowed automatic upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. 3. I can enter terminal with ctl+alt+f4 but no commands work

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to recover the files would be to open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the command:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Now keep the terminal window open (otherwise the file browser will close) and you can access any area of the disk with that file window.

You can also likely recover your system by booting it into Recovery Mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the initial boot of the PC to get the menu. You will be given multiple options like checking/repairing disk or fixing broken packages.

Comment: when in terminal through ctrl+alt+T I see the window with the folders (that workable with the mouse) but when I enter "home" then "documents" no folders or files are visible. I'd be surprised if I could. In that case any pearson with a memory stick and ubuntu on it could access data just booting from usb. During the process no pw were asked at any stage. Is there a way to boot from usb and have admin access?

Comment: Unless you enable BitLocker in Windows (or some other encryption system) all of your files can be viewed by anyone with physical access to your computer. Modern versions of Windows put the files in the `C:\Users` directory. Running the command `sudo` is giving it `root` privileges, which is similar to "admin" access in Windows.

Comment: I understand. However I tried to study how to copy the .thunderbird folder to a usb disk and I found few tutorials. It didn't work. It says "failed to preserve ownership for /path/filename ... operation not permitted"

Comment: @GianAndrea Was that while copying from within Windows or while accessing your Windows disk using Ubuntu?

Comment: I do not have windows. Not at all, not even as dual boot. Only Ubuntu 16.04. I was trying to copy within sudo the ".thunderbird" folder to the usb stick

Comment: You'll likely want to change the user of the `.thunderbird` files after you copy them, using this command: `sudo chown someuser:someuser /home/someuser/thunderbird`

Comment: thank you, I have decided to install erase the HD. I'll recover thunderbird mails from the server